# CakePHP3 API request PUT method compatiblity issue

Tags: javascript, cakephp-3.0, crud, restful-authentication

I am using the Cakephp3 CRUD plugin to provide a Resful API. My frontend is using Angular.js. I am implementing a user story which facilitates image upload via a form.

Since I am dealing with images I need to pass a FormData object to the backend. This work fine for my Add method which is a POST request. However when it comes to the Edit I should use a PUT method. The edit doesn't work and I believe this is because PUT is not comaptible with form-data.

I have seen similar question asked concerning Laravel, for that frame work there is a workaround in which a hidden field "_method" can be sent with a POST request.

Is there a similar solution for CakePHP's Crud plugin?

**Update**

By "does not work" I mean that any new changes which I post to the API "edit" method are not saved. Further if I debug the entity in the beforeSave of the edit method I see the  currently saved entity - without the difference I am trying to save from the input.

For the "add" method which "does work" if I debug the same object I see the new entity data which I expect to see and wish to save.

Comment: Try using a [PATCH](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/PATCH) request instead. Since it appears you're only doing a partial update on the object, a PATCH should be a more appropriate request.

Comment: @TechGnome is PATCH compatiable with form-data?

Comment: Both PATCH and PUT are allowed to submit a request body. This hidden field thing is just a "workaround" to the limitation that HTML forms are only allowed to use GET or POST, so that shouldn't be a concern for your REST API. It may help if you show your debugging results, and elaborate on the "_doesn't work_" part, which could mean basically anything.

Comment: @ndm please see the update to my question

Comment: Check what `$this->request->getData()` and `$this->request->input()` are, also make sure that your request actually sends any data (and that it is in the correct format), and that it sends the `Content-Type` header with a value of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. [**This code**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.8.4/src/Http/ServerRequest.php#L386-L391) in the server request should handle the input, and [**this code**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.8.4/src/Controller/Component/RequestHandlerComponent.php#L225-L226) in the request handler component shouldn't run.

Comment: @ndm when making a POST request I have to set the header with: Content-Type': undefined - when I debug the request data I see the correct expected format and the entity saves. For the PUT I set the header as 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', the update doesn't save and the request data debug is like this: https://pastebin.com/BzqtQHwc

Comment: Also note that I using the FOC CRUD plugin, i'm not sure if this is significant?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I mixed things up, the correct `Content-Type` header would of course be `multipart/form-data` if you want to send files, but CakePHP doesn't support that, it only supports `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. So for a clean API you'd have to parse the data yourself (for example in a middleware), alternatively you'll have to resort to a method override workaround, ie make a `POST` request and send either a `X-Http-Method-Override` header or a `_method` field that holds `PUT`.

Comment: @ndm thanksm I have tried using POST with PUT override, I can see in the request header: Content-Type: multipart/form-data, X-Http-Method-Override: PUT. The request data is still empty and the entity doesn't update...

Comment: Ok so I found the issue and it is related to the "boundary". I am making the request via Angular, I found this information: "By setting ‘Content-Type’: undefined, the browser sets the Content-Type to multipart/form-data for us and fills in the correct boundary. Manually setting ‘Content-Type’: multipart/form-data will fail to fill in the boundary parameter of the request."

Answer (score 0):

So in answer to my own question, the solution is a similar approach to that used in the question which I alluded to in my question.

In the main since I need to use a PUT method and this is not compatible with FormData I need to override the method with a POST. The headers of my request are therefore:

```
headers: {
     "Content-Type": undefined,
     "X-HTTP-Method-Override": "PUT"
}
```

It is also key to set the content-type to be undefined. I expected to have to explicitly set type to be multi-part but this in doing so the "boundary" of the request is not set and the API cannot parse the request. By set undefined the Angular front-end detects the multi-part type and sets the boundary for me.

Thank you to @ndm for the patience shown and helping me to discover the solution.